# OpenCV + ARToolkit

Tags: opencv, augmented-reality, artoolkit

For school, I have to do an augmented reality project. ARToolkit is good for tracking markers but my problem is my procamcalib calibration can't be used by artoolkit (distortion coefficient in procamcalib and distortion factor in artoolkit).

I see that with openCV i can calibrate my ps eye and can apply the undistortion directly.

So my question is can get the ps eye image, undistorted it and give it to artoolkit after to have my markers's positions?

Thanks
(Sorry for my english, I'm a french student, if you've got some troubles to read I can explain again)

Answer (score 0):

might be a bit of work to de-couple the video code, but in the end you can use just:

```
arDetectMarker(dataPtr, thresh, &marker_info, &marker_num)
```

with pixels from anywhere ( e.g an undistorted opencv-Mat from your pseye )

Comment: So I have to use OpenCV to read the video stream, undistorted it and give it to the arDetectMarker function? Because it's the only reason I want to use OpenCV, just to use my calibration in ARToolKit.

Edit: Or maybe I can use a calibration tool who give me the distortion factor?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if I understanded your question. But you could run the example calibration program that comes with ARToolKit. More information could be found here: [Calibrating Your Camera](https://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=2_Configuration:config_camera_calibration)

Then you would be able to get the calibration result "camera_para.dat" at ARToolKit's bin/Data, which could be used later in your project.

If by any chance you are using Unity for your AR project (If not, ignore below), simply import the ARToolKit, then in the AR Controller inspector, give your .dat file a unique name, then include it in "Camera Parameters" option.